# Extract core functionalities out of a class

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns

I have a public class `A`. This class would be used at both client as well as server side. But at the server end it would have lesser APIs exposed (client environment specific APIs would not be present).  So, I am extracting the core APIs common to both the environments into an abstract hidden super class `ASuper`. That is splitting `A` into `A` and `ASuper`.

 The problem I am facing in doing this is that many of the core APIs return object of type `<T extends A>`. Hence, a super-class is referring its sub-class which is against principles of inheritance. I don't want to override each such API in A (due to large number of these APIs). I don't want to change methods signature to `<T extends ASuper>` either. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Too much prose. Try to create a minimal example that reproduces your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No one will be able to help you more than the last time you asked this question unless you post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the right solution will be do what you are trying to aviod — to change the signatures. Even better, extract interface from your `ASuper` and make your API return this interface instead of concrete implementation.

However if you need some workaround, I can imaging only this approach: Instead of extracting superclass `ASuper` extract child class `AChild`. In this case your existent methods will be returning superclass `A` instead of child class. Later you can rename both parent and child classes (I hope your IDE supports this kind of refactoring).

Answer (score 0):

You should not refactor ASuper to be a super class of A, because as you point out that would create a bad inheritance structure. You should follow the principals of [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and pass an instance of ASuper to the constructor of A.